Booting a MBR table partitioned HDD on a PC that only supports UEFI booting
I have a hard disk image (Debian 12).
It was installed in BIOS boot mode on an older PC. The OS is setup with pre-installed applications and tools.
I would like to write this image to multiple HDD's and use it as a pre-setup OS on all future projects. Unfortunately, the industrial panel PC's my supplier offers, only supports UEFI and refuses to boot. How can I boot to a bios boot prepared HDD when the PC only supports UEFI?

Is there any reason why you can't just convert it to a GPT/UEFI disk? You can usually do this in-place fairly reliably.

I have no reason not to convert, I am asking for help on how to do something like that. As I spent many hours setting the OS up, I would prefer not re-installing it. If it's possible to use my image to a new hdd and then converting to uefi boot without compromising the OS install, that is exactly what I need. The "how" of the fact.

Create a VMWare VM from the hdd using the VMWare Converter application, outside of that, time to upgrade to an OS that supports UEFI.

@Ramhound, Debian 12 does support UEFI, the point is I don't want to have to do a clean install. I am looking for a "how" to use my existing image.

I am aware of no tool for Linux that will allow you to convert MBR to GPT in order to accomplish that conversion without data loss.

@Ramhound, there are plenty of tools that can convert from MBR to GPT without affecting data, gdisk can do it see this and this previous SuperUser question(s). If OP has a disk image and isn't doing this in place, can even just create the partition table first and then restore just the OS partition instead of whole disk. Ofc you'd also need to create an ESP and run grub-install again.

@timuzhti I am not aware of a tool. I didn’t say there wasn’t one.

MicroSpec: I posted an answer to a question similar to yours. I tried to get your question reopened so I could post an answer, but the attempt was rejected.  I think it would have been helpful if you would have included information such as the type of drives involved and their sector sizes. Also, listing the partitions on the MBR drive would have been useful. For example, posting the output from the command lsblk.
